# Проект для начинающего по андроиду

Tags: android

Всем привет.

Есть задание по учёбе - написать любую программу для андроид ..

Появилась идея - по поводу написания снифера сети(понял что пока не по силе) и решил отложить.

Всеравно в поиске идей..

(Интересует в основном приложения для сети, для самой OS такие как отслеживание процессов системы, на подобие программы AIDA64,отслежка трафика,менеджер паролей).

Эти приложения представляют личный интерес для меня, хотел узнать - подходят ли перечислинные для начинаюшего проекта по андроид ?

Имею опыт практики готового проекта в JavaCore/JavaEE(Web Services with jersey framework)+ Mysql..

Всё некак немогу прийти к выводу что подойдёт..

Если кто сможет направить и дать пару дельных советов буду рад!

Comment: Любую – напишите примитивно простую оригинальную игру (чтобы похожей не было в Play Market). Вообще здесь не место таким вопросам: тут любят конкретные задачи и проблемы, а не творческие искания. Попробуйте спросить на [Toster](https://toster.ru/)'е.

Comment: Не склонен к играм..

Comment: Ещё давно была идея – примочка поверх карт (географических) – позволяющая отловить Солнце или Луну в точной позиции относительно местности. Напр. я турист, хочу сделать фото полной Луны в конце Тверской улицы: ставлю маркеры фотографа и Луны с высотой на карте – и апп покажет, в какие даты такой кадр сделать можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напиши погодное приложение. Если цель обучиться большому стэку технологий и нет цели заработать (так как конкуренция в этой нише просто колоссальная), то вперед.
В результате получишь опыт работы с многими нужными библиотеками: Retrofit, Okhttp, карты и многое многое другое. Тема настолько обширная, что только бы хватило фантазии.
Советую это направление, так как сам начинал с погоды :-)

PS: Если ты новичек в Андроид-разработке на udacity есть бесплатный обучающий курс, где как раз пишут погодное приложение: довольно-таки неплохое подспорье для первого раза.

Comment: разве OkHTTP и Retrofit оба не REST-клиенты, только от разных команд. То есть делают одно и тоже, зачем они обе в одном приложении ..

Comment: это продукты одной комманды. Retrofit это надстройка над OkHttp